# How can I see diagnostic debug info in my Slick tests to fix poor performance?

Tags: scala, logging, slf4j, slick, scalatest

I'm having trouble figuring out what's happening with slow-executing integrations tests, using Slick to write to the database. But, I can't figure out how to access diagnostic logging, via SLF4J.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually figured this out on my own, and there are two components to the answer.

**Poor performance**

I realized that my poor performance was on account of synchronous testing of async APIs. I am using Scalatest along with Scalacheck property-based testing, and using the [`futureValue`](http://christopher-batey.blogspot.com/2014/02/testing-scala-futures-with-scalatest-20.html) approach to blocking on async requests. For some reason, I had set the `interval` of the [`PatienceConfiguration`](http://www.artima.com/docs-scalatest-3.0.0-M15/#org.scalatest.concurrent.PatienceConfiguration) to 500ms, and so every `futureValue` call was taking at least a half second, even though the database queries themselves usually executed in at most 20ms, and usually <10ms. I eventually turned the interval down to 2ms, and performance was greatly improved.

Scalatest 3 has proper async test support, although as of 3.0.0-M15, `GeneratorDrivenPropertyChecks` does not currently support async. This [might change](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scalatest-users/Amvqg9pgyNg).

**Diagnostic logging**

I installed the SLF4J simple logging backend with the SBT `libraryDependencies` entry of `"org.slf4j" % "slf4j-simple" % "1.7.12"`. I could not get it to work properly by setting the [simple logger properties](http://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/impl/SimpleLogger.html) through `application.conf`.

I set a Java system property to tell SLF4J-simple to log in debug mode `org.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel=debug` and then running `test` at the SBT prompt. Because this resulted in an absurd amount of output from the Slick query compiler, I set the debug output for the loggers of that compiler back to `info`, which largely squelched the extra output, by adding the property `org.slf4j.simpleLogger.log.slick.compiler=info`. You can modify logger-levels that match a prefix in this way.

Actually setting the properties turned out to be a non-trivial problem. I tried several approaches:

- Setting the property via Typesafe config (`test/resources/application.conf`) by adding `org.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel=debug` did *not* work. Typically, this is the case for things that are set up by system properties before the config is parsed, so I assume this is the case for the logger.
- Setting the property from the command line when starting up SBT worked, by starting SBT with `sbt -Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel=debug`, but *only* when running tests in a non-forked JVM with the SBT setting `fork in test := false`.
- Setting the property from SBT using `javaOptions += "org.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel=debug"` did *not* work, forked JVM or not.
- Setting the property by adding `org.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel=debug` to `test/resources/simplelogger.properties` worked for both forked JVM and unforked.